# AsyncTask throwing Error "Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Void[]" on doinbackground()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My Asynctask is throwing this error

```
"Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Void[]"
```

code:

```
protected Object doInBackground(Void... params)
```

on above method for only specific user not for all users.Can any one tell does passing void like "AsyncTask Void,Void,Object" is cause for my problem? below i attach my code

```
private class RegisterTask extends 
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object>      
       {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }
    protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}`
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the parameter passed to `new RegisterTask().execute()` method. Perhaps you used `Object` type rather than `Void`.

Change your `RegisterTask` class to extend `AsyncTask <Object, Void, Object>`. Learn more about `AsyncTask` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example).

Comment: This issue for only specific user only im not able to replicate this issue.im not sure that changing " Void to Object"  fix my issue.Any way thanks for support.code running successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the AsyncTask with an Object as a parameter even if you not used it would not harm

```
private class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object>      
    {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Alternate is the way you have been initializing your AsyncTask is it a generic way like ?

```
//Change
AsyncTask asyncTask = new  RegisterTask (...);
```

Then please remove above and create your AsyncTask with the correct parameter declaration side.

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object> asyncTask = new  RegisterTask (...);
```